# How to use a variable in an LDAP command in C?

Tags: c, ldap, openldap

I would like to use a variable in the ldap command ldap_search_s in C. I used strcat to create the string i needed. The error is "bad search filter". I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the string i have created. Here is my code:

```
char *numero = randomID1() ;
 char *var1="\"(studentID=";
 char *var2= numero;
 char *var3= ")\" ";
char var4[80];


 strcpy (var4,var1);
  strcat (var4, var2);
  strcat (var4,var3);
char *attr[] = { "cn","sn","studentID", NULL };



ldap_search_s( ld, "dc=******,dc=fr",
               LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, var4, attr , 0 , &res )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but after looking at the documentation, I would suspect you should not include the double quotes in the filter:

```
char *var1="(studentID=";
char *var2= numero;
char *var3= ")";
```

Comment: that whole thing would look better with `s(n)printf` IMO.

Comment: @Mat:  I agree.  I waver, though, in my responses between trying to answer the question strictly as asked versus trying to point out other potential issues (e.g., cleaner code, possible buffer overruns, etc.).

Comment: @Dyaz: Cool.  Glad you got it working.  If it was the "solution", you can click the check mark next to the answer to accept it as the solution, but that is your choice.